# Updating jenkins job variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Parameterized variable are not getting updated in jenkins

I m  using the conditional build-step plugin to update the jenkins job parameter by executing shell script its showing me the new value of variable as well but its not get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the EnvInject Plugin. One of the features is a build step that allows you to "inject" parameters into the build job from a settings file.

Create a property for the email list in the env.properties file:

```
echo "variable=`value`"> env.properties
```

It will create the properties file in the job workspace directory.

```
env.properties
```

In shell script:

```
"$variable"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to change the value of a pre-defined parameter
from within a script that is run by the job.
This will not work, because of "scope" (or "call-stack"),
as a process (your script) cannot change the environment of a parent process (your Jenkins job).

Comment: My friend I m able to see the value of this variable in different scope of executing shell script "I have mentioned that I m able to access that variable but not able to change it" I thought so these parameters may be treated as a constant by jenkins..................

Comment: Yes, this is probably the reason: you see it and can change it locally in the shell (because you have a local copy of it), but it will not get updated in the main job, because it's a different scope. Same will happen if you run a script from another script, and expect the child-script to change a parameter in the parent-script.